# sed regular expression query

Tags: regex, unix, sed

To change the Tomcat password in the following line

```
<user username="user1" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
```

I'm trying

```
sed -i s/'username=\"user1\" password=\".*\"'/'username=\"user1\" password=\"NEWPASS\"'/g tomcat-users.xml
```

but the resulting line will be

```
<user username="user1" password="NEWPASS"/>
```

How do I change the regular expression to not cut off the last attribute?
I want it to look like

```
<user username="user1" password="NEWPASS" roles="tomcat"/>
```

Comment: `/<user username="user1"/` or, depending 'XML' content you could change other line having this part of pattern. But i agree that on this sample, assuming there are only `<user` tag, this is enough

Answer (score 2):

Try the following substitution:

```
sed -i 's/password="[^"]*"/password="NEWPASS"/' tomcat-users.xml
```

If you want to do the substitution only in the line corresponding to user1, specify a [regexp address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html#Addresses):

```
sed -i '/username="user1"/ s/password="[^"]*"/password="NEWPASS"/' tomcat-users.xml
```

Explanation:

```
# for lines that match
# this regexp...
# ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
'/username="user1"/ s/password="[^"]*"/password="NEWPASS"/'
#                   ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
#                    ...execute this command.
```

Comment: very nice explanation but unfortunately the second command didn't work.. char 22: extra characters after command

Comment: That's weird, it works for me. Which version of sed do you have? If I run `sed --version` i get `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed 's~\(<user username="user1" password="\)[^"]*~\1NEWPASS~g' file
<user username="user1" password="NEWPASS" roles="tomcat"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you only want to do this for lines that contain `username="user1"`. So, you could do

```
sed -i '/username="user1"/{s/password="[^"]*"/password="NEWPASS"/}
```

The idea is to find any lines that contain `username="user1"` and run the script only on those. This is achieved by the `/foo/{...}` syntax. Then, you identify the password by looking for the longest stretch of non-`"` after `password="` and replace the whole thing with the new version.

There is no need for `g`, that makes sed replace all occurrences in any single line ans is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Less is more. Replace the g with a 1

```
sed -i s/tomcat/NEWPASS/1 tomcat-users.xml
```